# Powering an old TI Silent 707 with a missing external AC/AC adapter

Tags: power-supply, ac, connector, vintage

I just got my hands on a [TI Silent 700 model 707](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images1/1/0317/30/texas-instruments-silent-700-model_1_0beb9fd0b5d54c2d8c0d006eda918ca5.jpg), but it's missing the external power transformer. Unlike similar Silent 700 models, this features an optional battery pack which complicates things beyond my understanding.

Normally I would just look at the back to see how many volts to whack in but it looks like this thing wants AC power, which I haven't seen before at non-mains levels.
[image: the back]

Mildly confused I looked into the datasheet to become *more* confused because this seems to contradict the block diagram which claims 28V:

[image]

Lucky for us, the schematics for the thing are available in the maintenance manual in [this PDF](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ti/terminal/silent_700/2310453-0001_Model_703_707_Data_Terminals_Maintenance_Manual_Feb84.pdf) on page 90 which I have reproduced here:

[image: Power Supply Schematic]

So, how do I power this thing? Given it accepts battery power, I'm inclined to use a 16V DC source directly into where the battery plugs are (they are readily exposed), but I'm not *certain* this won't cause any issues. Alternatively, assuming the 20VAC number is correct, I can purchase a mains to 20VAC wall adapter such as the [WAU20-2000](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/WAU20-2000/237-1889-ND/4915303?itemSeq=353575334) from Triad Magnetics.

P.S. Does anybody know what kind of connector this is? I wasn't able to find any reference to it's type in the manual. [image: connector]

EDIT: After more snooping I have confirmed the AC adapter [is indeed 20VAC](https://ingeniumcanada.org/ingenium/collection-research/collection-item.php?id=1997.0813.002)

Comment: Either go with the 16VDC to the battery connectors, or replace the AC connector with something current and use the adaptor. I can't honestly see why you're even asking. The AC specs are clearly stated on the label, and 16V DC is just that. Either should work.

Comment: Looks like it uses a std IEC power plug used by PC’s

Answer (score 1):

> it looks like this thing wants AC power, which I haven't seen before at non-mains levels

But... that's exactly what you get at the output of any step-down transformer that feeds a low voltage rectifier etc.

It looks like the external supply is just a transformer and a fuse in a case, and the rectification and everything else is done inside.

You could just feed DC instead, it's going to be rectified anyway. 16V plus two diode drops is what you need, so about 18VDC.

Comment: `two diode drops` three: two in CR15 and another one in CR20.

Answer (score -2):

/ WATTS 150 W  120V. Standard IEC Plug

[image]

Is this your model?  I suppose the isolation transformer is necessary for preventing 0Vdc from being offset from Neutral or miswired Hot to neutral swaps.

**Yes I would use a 65W min 16V universal power supply.** It has a non isolated DC to Dc converter, so other than possible EMI crosstalk, and charging up 3.3mF cap on startup before turning ON pwr switch,  it should work...

The 150W AC rating is generous for power on surge and charger losses.

Comment: This is a different model, looks like the 745. It has a standard power connector unlike the 707.